# Java Executable Script

Tags: bash

I want to make an executable for my program. Let's just say it's called Tomato. The program will accept more than one argument, and some of the arguments might contain white spaces, so I will surround them with quotation marks. An example of the arguments would be:

```
"Leonardo DiCaprio" "Will Ferrel" OtherName "Gwyneth Paltrow"
```

Right now, this is what my script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -cp derived/tomato.jar:lib/* tomato.Main $*
```

I'm guessing I need to change the '$*', but I'm not sure to what. When I run it in eclipse, it works fine, but when I try to run in using my executable, it doesn't work..

Comment: please be more specific. what error message do you get ?

Comment: You may find [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) useful. Given your script, it points to the `$*` and says "Use "$@" (with quotes) to prevent whitespace problems."

Comment: Potentially a good question if the title was more specific to the actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm guessing I need to change the '$*', but I'm not sure to what.

Indeed. You need to change it to `"$@"`. The double-quotes prevent the parameters from undergoing word splitting and filename-expansion. Using `"$@"` instead of `"$*"` causes the parameters to be split from each other, however, which is what you need.

For example, if the arguments are (as in your example) `Leonardo DiCaprio`, `Will Ferrel`, `OtherName`, `Gwyneth Paltrow`, then:

- `$*` expands to `Leonardo`, `DiCaprio`, `Will`, `Ferrel`, `OtherName`, `Gwyneth`, `Paltrow`
- `$@` expands to `Leonardo`, `DiCaprio`, `Will`, `Ferrel`, `OtherName`, `Gwyneth`, `Paltrow` (same as previous)
- `"$*"` expands to `Leonardo DiCaprio Will Ferrel OtherName Gwyneth Paltrow` (one big argument)
- `"$@"` expands to `Leonardo DiCaprio`, `Will Ferrel`, `OtherName`, `Gwyneth Paltrow` (as desired)

`"$@"` is almost *always* what you want. About the only time you'd want one of the others is if you're modifying existing poorly-written code that depends on the behavior of one of the others. Such code is fragile, but often quite hard to fix.